# Add before and after the string

Tags: php, string, replace, concatenation

```
$variable = 'for linebreak add 2 spaces at end';
```

Value of this variable everytime changes.

**How to add some text or html before and after this string?**

---

E.g. if we want to add `'<div>'` before and `'</div>'` after, string should look like:

```
$variable = '<div>for linebreak add 2 spaces at end</div>';
```

Comment: how is this different from the question you posted 15 minutes ago? Are you having a hard time understanding string concatenation? (No snark intended)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marko's solution is the way to go for simple cases. If you need to concatenate many strings, it is said that joining arrays is much faster.

```
$string[]='<div>';
$string[]= $variable;
$string[]='</div>';
$string = join('',$string);
```

Comment: For the **system time**, the faster way (0.003 second) is to use join arrays (with unset) in `PHP 7.2.0`.

Comment: For the **user time**, the faster way (0.003 second) is to use oneline concatenation without unset in `PHP 7.0.22`.

Comment: For **memory usage**, the "most ecomonical" (14.47 MiB) way is to use join array without unset in `PHP 7.0.14`.

Answer (score 13):

```
$wrapped_variable = '<div>' . $variable . '</div>';
```

Comment: @Happy: why you think this is not a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you want. Is this it?

```
<?php
function add_div($string){return '<div>'.$string.'</div>';}
$variable = 'for linebreak add 2 spaces at end'; 
echo add_div($variable); // <div>for linebreak add 2 spaces at end</div>
?>
```

If it isn't, say so and I will try again the next time I visit this page.

Answer (score 1):

## What is the faster ways?

### 1. Join arrays?

> ### 1.1 Join arrays (with unset)
>
> The code below :
>
> ```
> for($i=1;$i<1000;$i++){
>     $string[]='lorem_';
>     $string[]= $i;
>     $string[]='_ipsum';
>     $string = join('',$string);
>     var_dump($string);
>     unset($string);
> }
> ```
>
> generate this average performance:
>
> ```
> .---------.----------------.--------------.--------------.
> | Version | System time(s) | User time(s) | Memory (MiB) |
> |---------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
> |   5.6   |      0.016     |     0.061    |    20.60     |
> |   7.0   |      0.009     |     0.010    |    16.69     |
> |   7.1   |      0.011     |     0.011    |    24.18     |
> |   7.2   |      0.003     |     0.017    |    19.41     |
> '---------'----------------'--------------'--------------'
> ```
>
> *source: https://3v4l.org/8YK1H/perf#output*
>
> ---
>
> ### 1.2 Join arrays (without unset)
>
> The code below :
>
> ```
> for($i=1;$i<1000;$i++){
>     $string = [];
>     $string[]='lorem_';
>     $string[]= $i;
>     $string[]='_ipsum';
>     $string = join('',$string);
>     var_dump($string);
>     // unset($string);
> }
> ```
>
> generate this average performance:
>
> ```
> .---------.----------------.--------------.--------------.
> | Version | System time(s) | User time(s) | Memory (MiB) |
> |---------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
> |   5.6   |      0.017     |     0.068    |    20.58     |
> |   7.0   |      0.012     |     0.013    |    16.13     |
> |   7.1   |      0.021     |     0.012    |    23.23     |
> |   7.2   |      0.013     |     0.010    |    17.65     |
> '---------'----------------'--------------'--------------'
> ```
>
> *source: https://3v4l.org/kU4QG/perf#output*

---

### 2. Shorthand operator?

> ### 2.1 Shorthand operator (with unset)
>
> The code below :
>
> ```
> for($i=1;$i<1000;$i++){
>     $string = 'lorem_';
>     $string .= $i;
>     $string .= '_ipsum';
>     // $string = join('',$string);
>     var_dump($string);
>     unset($string);
> }
> ```
>
> generate this average performance:
>
> ```
> .---------.----------------.--------------.--------------.
> | Version | System time(s) | User time(s) | Memory (MiB) |
> |---------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
> |   5.6   |      0.012     |     0.059    |    20.60     |
> |   7.0   |      0.008     |     0.011    |    16.65     |
> |   7.1   |      0.014     |     0.012    |    24.22     |
> |   7.2   |      0.012     |     0.009    |    19.08     |
> '---------'----------------'--------------'--------------'
> ```
>
> *source: https://3v4l.org/cCoSC/perf#output*
>
> ---
>
> ### 2.2 Shorthand operator (without unset)
>
> The code below :
>
> ```
> for($i=1;$i<1000;$i++){
>     $string = 'lorem_';
>     $string .= $i;
>     $string .= '_ipsum';
>     // $string = join('',$string);
>     var_dump($string);
>     // unset($string);
> }
> ```
>
> generate this average performance:
>
> ```
> .---------.----------------.--------------.--------------.
> | Version | System time(s) | User time(s) | Memory (MiB) |
> |---------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
> |   5.6   |      0.011     |     0.059    |    20.60     |
> |   7.0   |      0.008     |     0.011    |    16.70     |
> |   7.1   |      0.014     |     0.011    |    24.22     |
> |   7.2   |      0.010     |     0.010    |    19.33     |
> '---------'----------------'--------------'--------------'
> ```
>
> *source: https://3v4l.org/iKnaV/perf#output*

---

### 3. One line concat?

> ### 3.1 One line concatenation (with unset)
>
> The code below :
>
> ```
> for($i=1;$i<1000;$i++){
>     $string = 'lorem_' . $i . '_ipsum';
>     // $string .= $i;
>     // $string .= '_ipsum';
>     // $string = join('',$string);
>     var_dump($string);
>     unset($string);
> }
> ```
>
> generate this average performance:
>
> ```
> .---------.----------------.--------------.--------------.
> | Version | System time(s) | User time(s) | Memory (MiB) |
> |---------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
> |   5.6   |      0.015     |     0.066    |    20.60     |
> |   7.0   |      0.008     |     0.012    |    16.68     |
> |   7.1   |      0.014     |     0.014    |    24.23     |
> |   7.2   |      0.010     |     0.014    |    19.45     |
> '---------'----------------'--------------'--------------'
> ```
>
> *source: https://3v4l.org/tv4X0/perf#output*
>
> ---
>
> ### 3.2 One line concatenation (without unset)
>
> The code below :
>
> ```
> for($i=1;$i<1000;$i++){
>     $string = 'lorem_' . $i . '_ipsum';
>     // $string .= $i;
>     // $string .= '_ipsum';
>     // $string = join('',$string);
>     var_dump($string);
>     // unset($string);
> }
> ```
>
> generate this average performance:
>
> ```
> .---------.----------------.--------------.--------------.
> | Version | System time(s) | User time(s) | Memory (MiB) |
> |---------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
> |   5.6   |      0.012     |     0.056    |    20.65     |
> |   7.0   |      0.008     |     0.008    |    16.69     |
> |   7.1   |      0.014     |     0.010    |    24.17     |
> |   7.2   |      0.007     |     0.011    |    19.39     |
> '---------'----------------'--------------'--------------'
> ```
>
> source: https://3v4l.org/mF0YW/perf#output

---

If merge all results by PHP version:

### `PHP 5.6`

```
.-------------.----------------.--------------.--------------.
|     Code    | System time(s) | User time(s) | Memory (MiB) |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         1.1 |      0.016     |     0.061    |    20.60     |
|         1.2 |      0.017     |     0.068    | >> 20.58     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 1 |      0.0165    |     0.0645   | >> 20.59     |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         2.1 |      0.012     |     0.059    |    20.60     |
|         2.2 |   >> 0.011     |     0.059    |    20.60     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 2 |   >> 0.0115    |  >> 0.059    |    20.60     |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         3.1 |      0.015     |     0.066    |    20.60     |
|         3.2 |      0.012     |  >> 0.056    |    20.65     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 3 |      0.0135    |     0.061    |    20.625    |
'-------------'----------------'--------------'--------------'
```

### `PHP 7.0`

```
.-------------.----------------.--------------.--------------.
|     Code    | System time(s) | User time(s) | Memory (MiB) |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         1.1 |      0.009     |     0.010    |    16.69     |
|         1.2 |      0.012     |     0.013    | >> 16.13     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 1 |      0.0105    |     0.0115   | >> 16.41     |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         2.1 |   >> 0.008     |     0.011    |    16.65     |
|         2.2 |   >> 0.008     |     0.011    |    16.70     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 2 |   >> 0.008     |     0.011    |    16.675    |     
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         3.1 |   >> 0.008     |     0.012    |    16.68     |
|         3.2 |   >> 0.008     |  >> 0.008    |    16.69     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 3 |   >> 0.008     |  >> 0.010    |    16.685    |
'-------------'----------------'--------------'--------------'
```

### `PHP 7.1`

```
.-------------.----------------.--------------.--------------.
|     Code    | System time(s) | User time(s) | Memory (MiB) |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         1.1 |   >> 0.011     |     0.011    |    24.18     |
|         1.2 |      0.021     |     0.012    | >> 23.23     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 1 |      0.016     |  >> 0.0115   | >> 23.705    |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         2.1 |      0.014     |     0.012    |    24.22     |
|         2.2 |      0.014     |     0.011    |    24.22     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 2 |   >> 0.014     |  >> 0.0115   |    24.22     |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         3.1 |      0.014     |     0.014    |    24.23     |
|         3.2 |      0.014     |  >> 0.010    |    24.17     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 3 |   >> 0.014     |     0.012    |    24.20     |
'-------------'----------------'--------------'--------------'
```

### `PHP 7.2`

```
.-------------.----------------.--------------.--------------.
|     Code    | System time(s) | User time(s) | Memory (MiB) |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         1.1 |   >> 0.003     |     0.017    |    19.41     |
|         1.2 |      0.013     |     0.010    | >> 17.65     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 1 |   >> 0.008     |     0.0135   | >> 18.53     |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         2.1 |      0.012     |  >> 0.009    |    19.08     |
|         2.2 |      0.010     |     0.010    |    19.33     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 2 |      0.011     |  >> 0.0905   |    19.205    |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|--------------|
|         3.1 |      0.010     |     0.014    |    19.45     |
|         3.2 |      0.007     |     0.011    |    19.39     |
|             |-- -- -- -- -- -|-- -- -- -- --|-- -- -- -- --|
| (average) 3 |      0.0085    |     0.0125   |    19.42     |
'-------------'----------------'--------------'--------------'
```

---

## Conclusion

- For the **system time**, the **faster** way (0.003 second) is to use **join arrays (with unset) in `PHP 7.2.0`**.
- For the **user time**, the **faster** way (0.003 second) is to use **oneline concatenation without unset in `PHP 7.0.22`**.
- For **memory usage**, the "**most ecomonical**" (14.47 MiB) way is to use **join array without unset in `PHP 7.0.14`**.