# Do stuff after iteration ends

Tags: php, iterator

Example:

```
class MyRecursiveIteratorIterator extends RecursiveIteratorIterator{

  public function current(){
    echo 'START';
    return parent::current();
  }

}

$it = new MyRecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));

foreach ($it as $key => $val){

  // here it starts

  echo $val;


  // here it ends
}
```

So what method should I implement in my class so I can insert my stuff after each element?

Comment: um, what? Could you add more explanation of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to echo generate a nested UL list. And iterate it like a single level list.. But I don't know how to close the last LI item automatically, because after the last element the iterator finishes..

Comment: So this has to do with generating HTML tags from a php array. Taking each element in the array and make an LI item out of it?

Comment: something like that, yes

Comment: essentially I need to know if there's are kind of startIteration and endIteration methods I don't know about.. (but for individual elements, not the whole list - I know there are two for the entire list)

Comment: Maybe you should start this whole question over. Tell what you are trying to do, ie what the output you want is. And tell how you are trying to accomplish that, ie what php code you have now. You can even make up pseudo-php code and ask "I know this isn't real but is there any way to do this for real?" Because as it is now, we are not on the same page, so helpful answers are unlikely.

Comment: As people said, probably overcomplicating things, but you want the `RecursiveCachingIterator` in that case, with `hasNext()` method...

Comment: Possible a duplicate of this (and this may also answer your question) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3747193/201648. You could make the function accept 2 arguments - 1 for the string and one of the tag like   function add_div($string,$tag){return '<'.$tag.'>'.$string.'</'.$tag.'>';}. As for recursive functions, here is a good tutorial - http://devzone.zend.com/283/recursion-in-php-tapping-unharnessed-power/ - let me know if this doesn't answer your question and I'll write some sample code.

Comment: You could also look at doing this as a decorator - http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/Decorator/ - which it looks like you've already started doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, here is code to echo the elements of a php array into a UL html list. If this is not what you're looking for please add additional information.

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($it as $val)
{
    echo "<li>" . $val . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you might be overcomplicating things.

```
public function outputAsHTMLList() {
   echo '<ul>';
   foreach ($this->data as $element) {
      echo '<li>' . $element . '</li>';
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
```